# can't call functions from avr/power.h although eclipse does recognize "#include <avr/power.h>" as valid

Tags: c++, eclipse, arduino, avr

Eclipse (4.12, Arduino) does recognize the below as valid, does not cause any compile issues.

```
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
```

however when I try to use a function from one of them such as `sleep_enable();` eclipse underlines it in read and says it can not be resolved.

Comment: <avr/io.h> works? Could you build this project and then check that compiler returns error with undefined reference to sleep_enable(); ? Maybe eclipse just didn't refresh/reindex files.

Comment: hmm it looks like you might be right including <avr/io.h> works, and it complies with no errors with sleep_enable(). Any idea how to force eclipse to refresh?

Comment: right click on project -> Index -> Freshen all files. This reindexing whole project.

Comment: had to rebuild it too, but it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: Then make it as resolved for other users. :-)